# Power Query : How to handle "DataSource.NotFound: File or Folder: We couldn't find the folder " error

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to get the folder contents using the query below and also handles the error. But still I'm getting the text with a warning icon - "DataSource.NotFound: File or Folder: We couldn't find the folder"
See the M-code below:

```
let
Source = Folder.Files("\\serverpath\Desktop\"), 

AlternativeOutput=#table(type table [Name=text,Extension=text,Availability=text], {{"Error", "Error", "Folder not available"}}),
TestForError= try Source,    



Output = 
        if TestForError[HasError] then AlternativeOutput 
        else Source
```

in 
Output

Answer (score 3):

You need to force evaluation of the Folder.Files at each try / otherwise attempt, using Table.Buffer

```
= try Table.Buffer(Folder.Files(path1)) otherwise Folder.Files(path2)
```

you can then evaluate multiple paths, such as the same onedrive account if used on different computers having different login credentials i.e named username on one pc, but user.name on another (e.g personal computer, work computer)

```
= let SourceA = try Folder.Files("C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Documents\"),
SourceB = try Folder.Files("C:\Users\User.name\OneDrive\Documents\"),
DynamicSource = try Table.Buffer(SourceA[Value])
otherwise Table.Buffer(SourceB[Value])
in DynamicSource
```

Comment: You legend, this was driving me absolutely mad. I think I agree that it's a bug, it's returning an error that just isn't being seen as an error by Try/Catch. The buffer then trying to something, and thats now throwing a working error can handle.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug, which explains why `try...otherwise` also doesn't work. The `HasError` field is returning false even though we get a `DataSource.NotFound` error. I've filed an item on our end to track this issue.

Comment: Also I would like to know why Power query has slow performance in Excel. While running files having some complex queries will open up 2-4 mashup containers which takes too much of memory. Some times it may cause memory death to machine.

Comment: This depends on what you are doing. Complex queries may not be sent back to the server, or the data source may not support sending queries to the server, so in that case those operations have to be performed locally. Disabling privacy levels may offer a speed boost, but be sure that you're not accidentally sending sensitive information to a public source, like an Internet site.

Comment: Could you please help me on this topic?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442192/how-to-calculate-conditional-running-total-in-power-query-excel-2016

Answer (score 0):

As I needed this, and can confirm @Alejandro bug still happens (`DataSource.NotFound` still raises no `HasError` flag in 2023), I had to combine both of the previous answers to make it work:

```
let
    mainPath = "\\my-distant-srv\distant_dir\",
    testPath = try Table.Buffer(Folder.Files(mainPath)), // https://stackoverflow.com/a/60146119/5510196
    curatedPath = if (testPath)[HasError] = false then mainPath & "dist_file.csv" else "C:\temp\local_csv.csv", // https://stackoverflow.com/q/48637708/5510196
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(curatedPath),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in
    curatedPath
```

*When trying to populate `Table.Buffer`, emptiness raises the required `HasError`. This is then used through a `if.. then.. else` to curate the result.*

Thanks for your help!