# How to calculate conditional running total in power query (Excel 2016)?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible to calculate conditional based running total in power query? 
I need to add numbers(cumulative sum) based on the group. See the image attached.
Currently I'm using a formula to calculate that in sheet and loading it to query editor. Is there any other logic to achieve that in power query (if possible, without indexing : because index took too much time to load).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: AFAIK Index is all we have for this in PQ.  Try Table.Buffer e.g. after adding the index, or stage data in an Excel table.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I will try this.

Comment: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/running-total-by-category/ Very good article here on the topic.