# PowerBI: Check if the folder/directory we are loading to exists or not using Power Query

Tags: powerbi

I am a newbie in PowerBi and currently working on a POC where I need to load data from a folder or directory. Before this load, I need to check if
1) the respective folder exists 
2) the file under the folder is with.csv extension.

```
Ex. Let suppose we have a file '/MyDoc2004/myAction.csv'.
Here first we need to check if MyDoc2004 exists and then if myAction file is with.csv extension.
```

Is there any way we can do this using Power Query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power Query : How to handle "DataSource.NotFound: File or Folder: We couldn't find the folder " error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637708/power-query-how-to-handle-datasource-notfound-file-or-folder-we-couldnt-fi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Check if the folder exists

You can apply `Folder.Contents` function with the absolute path of the folder, and handle the error returned when the folder does not exist with `try ... otherwise ...` syntax.

```
let
    absoluteFolderPath = "C:/folder/that/may/not/exist",
    folderContentsOrError = Folder.Contents(absoluteFolderPath),
    alternativeResult = """" & absoluteFolderPath & """ is not a valid folder path",
    result = try folderContentsOrError otherwise alternativeResult
in
    result
```

### 2. Check if the file is with .csv extension

I'm not sure what output you are expecting.

Here is a way to get the content of the file by full path including ".csv", or return an alternative result if not found.

```
let
    absoluteFilePath = "C:/the/path/myAction.csv",
    fileContentsOrError = File.Contents(absoluteFilePath),
    alternativeResult = """" & absoluteFilePath & """ is not a valid file path",
    result = try fileContentsOrError otherwise alternativeResult
in
    result
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please update the question with the expected output.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Kosuke, Thank you for your time I appreciate. Our requirement was if the folder or the .csv file not exists it should not process the table. so can we do something like that?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Folder.Contents and File.Contents return an error when the item is not there. So you can trap the error and do some different operation as illustrated above.

Comment: I got the point but if File.Contents return an error the table should not be processed. As I mentioned it is new for me, Please help me with this.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are meaning by "table should not be processed". If it is not to define the table itself, it is impossible. But it is possible not to scan the file and create an empty table (or maybe create a table from another source) instead.

Comment: Thanks Kosuke, this answers my question. I am accepting your answer thanks again.